# Multiple timers in one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What im trying to do, is count the duration both my lamps are on.

I wrote this script to control switch the images and count the seconds but for some reason, the second image counts normally and the first one stops at one.

```
$("#changePic").live('click', function() {
            if ($(this).attr("class") == "changePicA") {
                this.src = this.src.replace("images/blackA","images/whiteA");
                timer=true; 
                myVar; 

            } else {
                this.src = this.src.replace("images/whiteA","images/blackA");
                timer=false; 

            }

            if ($(this).attr("class") == "changePicB") {
                this.src = this.src.replace("images/blackB","images/whiteB");
                timerA=true; 
                myVarA; 
            } else {
                this.src = this.src.replace("images/whiteB","images/blackB");
                timerA=false;
            }

            $(this).toggleClass("on");
        });

    });

    var myVar = setInterval(function(){ myTimer() }, 1000);
    var timer= false; 
    var seconds=0; 
    function myTimer() {

        if (timer){
            seconds++; 
            document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = seconds
            console.log("counting here");


        }else{

            clearInterval(seconds);
            document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = seconds;
            console.log("stopped counting here");
        }


    }
    var myVarA = setInterval(function(){ myTimerA() }, 1000);
    var timerA= false; 
    var secondsA=0; 
    function myTimerA() {

        if (timerA){
            secondsA++; 
            document.getElementById("counterA").innerHTML = secondsA;


        }else{

            clearInterval(seconds);
            document.getElementById("counterA").innerHTML = secondsA; 
        }


    }
```

my table looks like this:

```
<table class="buttonTable">
        <tr>
            <td><button class="equiptButton"><img src="images/blackA.jpg" id="changePic" class="changePicA"/></button></td>
            <td id="counter"></td><td id="counterA"></td>
            <td id="bill"> <button id= "estimatedbill" onclick="estimatedbill();">  Estimated bill:</button> <p>....</p></td>
            <td><button class="equiptButton"><img src="images/blackB.jpg" id="changePic" class="changePicB" /></button></td>    

            <td><button class="equiptButton"><img src="images/blackC.jpg" id="changePic" class="changePicC" /></button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Just a note: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers.

Comment: What exactly is your problem, if there is any exception, you should always append the log trace as well

Comment: you use `clearInterval(seconds)`, but your timer ids are saved in myVar, and myVarA

Comment: the only thing that doesn't work is the first timer, it counts 0, 1 then stops. But the second page continues to work as long as the page is loading. I want them both to work the same way

Comment: do you have multiple elements with the id changePic?  I'm wondering why you are assigning the click event to that element, and then checking wether it has the changePicB or changePicA classes.

Comment: yeah my table looks like this;

Answer (score 0):

As Samural said, .live() is deprecated.

To be clear: In modern versions of jQuery, your code would become something similar to:

```
$("body").on("click", "#changePic", function(){...});
```

That is, you are attaching even handler to the body and, then, every time check if the actual target which received the event matches your selector. This is useful if you want to implement event handlers which could work with elements that will be created in the future, but I think this is not the case. So it is sufficient to do something like:

```
$("#changePic").on("click", function(){...});
```

Also, I don't see your html, but, by your comments, I figure out you are trying to manage two images which seems to have the same id: That is illegal and you probably end up matching only the last one (but depends on the browser implementation because it is an unexpected situation).

On the other hand, I detect a *timer* variable not declared anywhere in that handler, but that matches with a another *timer* variable declared in global scope (so, if I'm not wrong, you are overridding it).

I suggest you to start your scripts with

```
"use strict";
```

...and then correct all the errors which will appear.

Comment: I understand all that, but that isn't my problem. I'll make all the changes necessary but for now I want to be able to get both timers to start

Comment: Obviously you did'nt understood. Dirty code is never the way to achieve nothing. Even less when you have variables supposed to be locals, overridding others in higher scope.